# Script in a embedded linux

Tags: linux, bash, embedded

I believe that this is a silly question but is my first time in wich I do a script. I am working on Linux, in an embedded system, and I think that what I want to do is quite simple but for me is not working.

I need to set an ip, start the startx & server for graphical mode and give to my application permission and run it, so I try like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#Start
#
echo "Start......"
ifconfig eth0 X.X.X.X
startx &
cd /home
chmod a+x myApplication
./myApplication
exit $?
```

And then I save my script like S80script and I put it in the /etc/init.d folder.

I ran it but after throw the startx server my application is not run.

How can I do this in a propertly way?
There is another way for do this?

Thank you so much and sorry because maybe it is a beginner question.

Comment: What embedded Linux distribution and system are you using?

Comment: Hi Basile thanks, is Linux linaro

Answer (score 0):

If your application need to acess the XServer than you need to export the DISPLAY environment variable.

Try to run the application using:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ./myApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install (for learning purposes) Linux on your laptop, and become familiar with Linux and scripting on your laptop. Then, replace during debugging phase the first line `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/sh -vx` or `#!/bin/bash -vx` if you can run that script in a terminal. You could also use [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) in your script. Read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) even if it is imperfect.

[startx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/startx) is configurable (read the linked man page), and is starting some client applications (configured in e.g. `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` or in `$HOME/.xinitrc`...); so you should start your  `$HOME/myApplication` from that file.

<sup>BTW, you could invoke `startx`  in some init script like `/etc/rc.local` or whatever is appropriate for your Linux distribution.</sup>

BTW, you almost certainly need a window manager (to be started *after* your backgrounded application, as the last command, probably in the same `xinitrc`....).

At last, your embedded Linux distribution probably has some other files and scripts to start the network. You should configure your network parameters appropriately (on Debian and related, you could do that in `/etc/network/interfaces`)

Comment: Hi Basile, well, my works application works nice, I do this steps: ifconfig eth0 X.X.X.X, cd /home, chmod a+x application, startx & and ./application. I do those step and my application works perfect, what I want to do is a script in which I execute all of this steps, nothing else.

Comment: My answer is still relevant; the environment for running the commands in a login terminal is not the same as the environment of initialization scripts.

Comment: Hi Basile thank you for your answer, but could you igve some example of what I need to do?thanks and sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Did you follow the links I gave above. They give some explanations and some examples. But I still strongly advise you to install and use Linux on your daily laptop or desktop.

Comment: Hi Basile I can not see any example or explanation for start the startx after boot in the link you told me. I only need to know how can I run the startx automatically when I switch my board on. Inside of /etc/X11 I just have an org.conf file nothing else.

Comment: BTW the ifconfig eth0 X.X.X.X works perfect, then when startx & is executed appear like a graphic mode but is seems that is not  propertly load.